# How to parse this data of unknown size

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple text file containing instructions per a line. e.g

```
A 1 1
B 2 1 A
C 3 1 A
D 4 1 B C
```

Basic syntax is Letter, Num, Num, Letter(s)

I just don't know what function I should be calling to parse the data, and how to parse it in the given syntax. I feel like there's so many ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do it. And the preferred way will be different depending on whether you write the code in C or C++. So you might want to pick a language, and then tell us what you've already tried.

Comment: @user3386109 Im more familiar with c which I would use getline, srtok.. But we can use c++ and I want to get familiar with it. So I want to find a way to do it in c++

Comment: In C++, you probably use a `getline` (but a different one from the POSIX one you'd use in C), and `std::string`, and then there are endless options on how you chop the string into pieces.

Comment: Shy away from `>>` for this one. `>>` will quietly consume the end of line marker.

Answer (score 0):

The following C++ example shows one of possible way to read single characters from file, controlling end of line:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream inpFile("test.txt");
    string str;
    char c;
    while (inpFile.good()) {
        // read line from file
        getline(inpFile, str);
        // make string stream for reading small pieces of data
        istringstream is(str);
        // read data ingnoring spaces
        do
        {
            is >> c; // read a single character
            if (!is.eof()) // after successful reading
                cout << c << " "; // output this character
        } while (is.good()); // control the stream state
        cout << "[End of line]" << endl;
    }
    cout << "[End of file]" << endl;
}
```

Here `istringstream` is used to process single line that is got by `getline`.

After reading a char with `is >> c` value in `c` can be checked for content, e.g.:

```
        if (!is.eof()) // after successful reading
        {
            // analyze the content
            if ( isdigit(c) )
                cout << (c - '0') << "(number) "; // output as a digit
            else
                cout << c << "(char) "; // output as a non-number
        }
```

Note: if file can contain not single characters / digits, but numbers and words, type of `c` should be appropriate (e.g. `string`)

Comment: The fact that there are both ``std::getline`` and a ``getline`` from C headers is a good example why ``using namespace std;`` is usually considered bad style.

Comment: why don't you just write `while(std::getline(inpFile, str))` and `while(is >> c)`? why do you expose `char c` to the outer level?

Comment: @JonasWielicki For such simple examples `using namespace std;` is quite possible, I suppose. John can rewrite without this `using` as he can

Comment: @Danh I did not claim to be the best or elegant solution, John can optimize it in any way

Answer (score 0):

In C++, read an entire line and make a stream from it, then read from that stream with `>>`.

Example:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string line;
while (file.getline(line))
{
    std::istringstream in(line);
    char letter;
    int number1;
    int number2;
    std::vector<char> letters;
    if (in >> letter >> number1 >> number2)
    {
        char letter2;
        while (in >> letter2)
        {
            letters.push_back(letter2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is C example that read lines, and then goes (using pointer) from the beginning to output readable characters (with code greater than 32):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80

int main(void)
{
    FILE * inpFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char *p;
    while (!feof(inpFile))
    {
        // read a line from file
        if (fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LEN, inpFile) != NULL)
        {
            p = buf; // start from the beginning of line
            // reading data from string till the end
            while (*p != '\n' && *p != '\0')
            {
                // skip spaces
                while (isspace(*p) && *p != '\n') p++;
                if (*p > 32)
                {
                    // output character
                    printf("%c ", *p);
                    // move to next
                    p++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("[End of line]\n");
    }
    printf("[End of file]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

To extract numbers and words from the line you can do something like:

```
        // reading data from string till the end
        while (*p != '\n' && *p != '\0')
        {
            // skip spaces
            while (isspace(*p) && *p != '\n') p++;
            if (*p > 32)
            {
                int num;
                char word[MAX_LINE_LEN];
                // trying to read number
                if (sscanf(p, "%i", &num))
                {
                    printf("%i(number) ", num);
                }
                else // read string
                {
                    sscanf(p, "%s", word);
                    printf("%s(string) ", word);
                }
                // move to next space in the simplest way
                while (*p > 32) p++;
            }
        }
```